# Completely remove the broken installation and merge its partition

Tags: grub2, partitioning

I have 2 bootable installations, one of them is broken, meaning I can't boot it but it does appear in the boot menu. I want to completely remove the broken one and merge its partition with the my current installation. How can I do this safely?

UPDATE:

I can't figure out how to merge sda1 and sda6, sda6 being my main partition.
[image]